# Disable a button in the first child div

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent-child

I've tried to create a simple application to swap divs on clicking the respective buttons.

However, the first div which is the first-child of div.container should have 'left' and 'top' button disabled.

I've tried to achieve this by finding the first child and changing the property of the button inside it to disabled. But this is lost and is not retained on the new first child when I swap the first-child.

Here's the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .box {
                height: 25%;
                width: 45%;
                padding: 1%;
                margin-left: 1%;    
                margin-top: 1%;
                border: 1px solid black;
                float: left;

            }

            .disabled-btn {
                cursor: not-allowed;
                opacity: 0.25%;
            }

        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box" id="one">
                <p>one</p>
                <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
                <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
                <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
                <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
            </div>

            <div class="box" id="two">
                <p>two</p>
                <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
                <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
                <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
                <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
            </div>

            <div class="box" id="three">
                <p>three</p>
                <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
                <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
                <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
                <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>

            </div>

            <div class="box" id="four">
                <p>four</p>
                <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
                <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
                <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
                <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                resetEvents();
            }

                function resertEvents() {

                    $('.right').unbind('click');
                    $('.left').unbind('click');
                    $('.top').unbind('click');
                    $('.down').unbind('click');


                    $('.right').click(function(){
                    //alert('ok');
                    var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
                    //toMove2 = toMove1.next();

                    $(toMove1).insertAfter($(toMove1).next());
                    });

                    $('.left').click(function(){
                        //alert('ok');
                        var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
                        //toMove2 = toMove1.prev();

                        $(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
                    });

                    $('.down').click(function(){
                        //alert('ok');
                        var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
                        var middle = $(toMove1).next();
                        var toMove2 = $(middle).next();

                        toMove2 = $(toMove1).insertAfter($(middle).next());

                        var middle = $(toMove2).prev();
                        //alert(middle);
                        middle = $(middle).insertBefore($(middle).prev());

                        //toMove2 = toMove1.prev();

                        //$(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
                    });

                    $('.top').click(function(){
                        //alert('ok');
                        var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
                        var middle = $(toMove1).prev();
                        var toMove2 = $(middle).prev();

                        toMove2 = $(toMove1).insertBefore($(middle).prev());

                        var middle = $(toMove2).next();
                        //alert(middle);
                        middle = $(middle).insertAfter($(middle).next());

                        //toMove2 = toMove1.prev();

                        //$(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
                    });

                }





            var firstChild = $('.container').children().first();
            var lastChild = $('.container').children().last();
            resetChild(firstChild, lastChild);


            });

            function resetChild(first, last) {
                var firstChild = $('.container').children().first();
                //console.log(firstChild);
                if(firstChild){
                    //$(firstChild).find('.left').prop('disabled', true);
                    $(firstChild).find('.left').addClass(disabled-btn);
                }

                var lastChild = $('.container').children().last();
                if(lastChild){
                    $(lastChild).find('.right').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Added [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/tqqL57ce/).

Comment: What you are trying to do here is unclear. I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/tqqL57ce/) for you. Can you exactly tell what is it that you are trying to do here?

Comment: I had updated the fiddle. Now, am able to swap based on the button clicks. However, for the first div if you see, ideally there are no left & top div to swap with. How do I make the buttons Swap with left & swap with top disable for the first div. Even after, the divs are swapped, it should still retain the swap with left & swap with top as disabled for whichever becomes the first-div after swapping.

Comment: Can you post the link to the updated fiddle?

Comment: Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/Sunny1719/tqqL57ce/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I went through your logic and modified and changed some aspect of your code for the better. The attached code is an improved version of what you have posted.

I created a function `handleEvents()` which should handle all your disable button properties on resetting of the layout and when two divs are swapped. This method has to be basically called on the swapping of all divs to render the new `disabled` properties on the buttons.

The function looks like this:

```
  function handleEvents() {
    $(".top, .left, .down, .right").prop("disabled", false);

    $(".container .box:first-child").find(".top, .left").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(2)").find(".top, .right").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(3)").find(".down, .left").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(4)").find(".down, .right").prop("disabled", true);
  }
```

Check updated solution in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/tqqL57ce/8/).

Refer the working solution here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  resetEvents();

  function handleEvents() {
    $(".top, .left, .down, .right").prop("disabled", false);

    $(".container .box:first-child").find(".top, .left").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(2)").find(".top, .right").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(3)").find(".down, .left").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".container .box:nth-child(4)").find(".down, .right").prop("disabled", true);
  }


  function resetEvents() {

    $(".top, .left, .down, .right").unbind('click');

    handleEvents();

    $('.right').click(function() {
      var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');

      $(toMove1).insertAfter($(toMove1).next());
      handleEvents();
    });

    $('.left').click(function() {
      var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');

      $(toMove1).insertBefore($(toMove1).prev());
      handleEvents();
    });

    $('.down').click(function() {
      var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
      var middle = $(toMove1).next();
      var toMove2 = $(middle).next();

      toMove2 = $(toMove1).insertAfter($(middle).next());

      var middle = $(toMove2).prev();
      middle = $(middle).insertBefore($(middle).prev());
      handleEvents();
    });

    $('.top').click(function() {
      var toMove1 = $(this).parents('.box');
      var middle = $(toMove1).prev();
      var toMove2 = $(middle).prev();

      toMove2 = $(toMove1).insertBefore($(middle).prev());

      var middle = $(toMove2).next();
      middle = $(middle).insertAfter($(middle).next());
      handleEvents();
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  height: 25%;
  width: 45%;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.disabled-btn {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" id="one">
      <p>one</p>
      <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
      <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
      <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
      <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="two">
      <p>two</p>
      <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
      <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
      <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
      <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="three">
      <p>three</p>
      <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
      <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
      <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
      <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>

    </div>

    <div class="box" id="four">
      <p>four</p>
      <button class="right">Swap with right!</button>
      <button class="left">Swap with left!</button>
      <button class="top">Swap with top!</button>
      <button class="down">Swap with down!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much...ok, how would I disable these buttons if the divs with the class box are dynamically generated...

Comment: If your elements are dynamically generated, you have to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) everywhere. Something like: `$(".container").on("click", ".left", function() { // your code });)`

Answer (score 1):

First we will configure all buttons as per your requirements.

- (top left), disable top and left
- (top right), disable top and right
- (bottom left), disable down and left
- (bottom right), disable down and right

[full jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/p0fb0hca/)

---

**Code**

```
function resetButtons() {
  // enable all buttons
    $("button").prop("disabled", false);

  // First box (top left), disable top and left
  var firstBox = $(".box").eq(0);
  firstBox.find(".top").prop("disabled", true)
  firstBox.find(".left").prop("disabled", true);

  // Second box (top right), disable top and right
  var secondBox = $(".box").eq(1);
  secondBox.find(".top").prop("disabled", true)
  secondBox.find(".right").prop("disabled", true);

  // Third box (bottom left), disable down and left
  var thirdBox = $(".box").eq(2);
  thirdBox.find(".down").prop("disabled", true)
  thirdBox.find(".left").prop("disabled", true);

  // Fourth box (bottom right), disable down and right
  var fourthBox = $(".box").eq(3);
  fourthBox.find(".down").prop("disabled", true)
  fourthBox.find(".right").prop("disabled", true);
}
```

For swapping, we will play with array-index of the boxes and swap the html content of each box.

```
function swapContent(divA, divB) {
  var tempDiv = divA.html();
  divA.html(divB.html());
  divB.html(tempDiv);
}
```

For example, **right button** will swap current box and the one next to it (on its right).

```
$(".container").on("click", ".right", function(e) {
  var currentBox = $(this).parents('.box');
  var currentIndex = $(".box").index(currentBox);
  console.log(currentIndex, "right", currentBox);

  swapContent(
    currentBox,
    $(".box").eq(currentIndex+1)
  );

  resetButtons();
});
```